# Oracle 11g Text: Composite Domain Index - FILTER BY on columns from different tables

Tags: oracle, indexing, dns, composite, oracle-text

I am using Oracle 11g Text,

**AuthorTable** : (a table for Author details)
AuthorId, AuthorName, AuthorDOB

**ArticleTable** : (a table for Article content) ArticleId, WrittenDate, PublishDate, ARTICLE_TXT (CLOB)

**LocationTable** : (a table for Location) LocationId, LocationState, LocationCity

**ArticleAuthorAssocTable**: (a table for Article-Author Association) AuthorId, ArticleId

**LocAuthorAssocTable**: (a table for Author-Location Association) AuthorId, LocationId, LocationStartDate, LocationEndDate

My query need to search for any input search term on ARTICLE_TXT along with any other query on PublishDate / WrittenDate / AuthorDOB / LocationCity / LocationStartDate range.

As I have to do a mixed-query, I started creating Composite Domain Index CDI on ArticleTable.

```
    CREATE INDEX ARTICLE_TXT_CDI_IDX ON ArticleTable(ARTICLE_TXT) 
    INDEXTYPE IS ctxsys.CONTEXT 
    FILTER BY WrittenDate, PublishDate
```

and the query as

```
SELECT 

/*+ domain_index_sort domain_index_filter(ARTICLE_TXT_CDI_IDX) */      article.ARTICLE_TXT, 

author.AuthorName , article.WrittenDate, article.PublishDate, LocationTable.LocationCity ,location.LocationStartDate, location.LocationEndDate 

FROM 

  ArticleTable article

  INNER JOIN 
  ArticleAuthorAssocTable  articleAuthorAssoc ON article.articleId = articleAuthorAssoc .articleId 

  INNER JOIN 
  AuthorTable author ON author.authorId= articleAuthorAssoc.authorId

  INNER JOIN 
  LocAuthorAssocTable locAuthorAssoc req ON author.authorId = locAuthorAssoc.authorId

INNER JOIN 
  LocationTable location ON location .authorId = locAuthorAssoc.authorId

WHERE

 CONTAINS(article.ARTICLE_TXT, 'Something') >0

 AND author.AuthorDOB BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2001','MM/DD/YYYY') 
AND TO_DATE('12/31/2012','MM/DD/YYYY')

 AND location.LocationId IN (1,2)
```

Now my questions are:

1. Is it possible to create Composite Domain Index with FILTER BY on
       columns from different tables ?
2. Is there any other way to improve the above query ?

From my research, some options are using materialized view, function-based index, USER_DATASTORE

But unfortunately still not sure how to use them... Please help me with your knowledge.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution to this problem is to add a XML column to the ArticleTable where you combine all the required info of the article.

Then you need to add triggers to the involved tables to recreate this xml when data changes are happening.

This way you could index this xml column and search for very specific information, using section groups (eg like 'PATH_SECTION_GROUP')